# How to mouse over a parent and child element in cypress

Tags: cypress

I am trying to automate the orangehrm website using cypress
(https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/index.php/auth/login)

My usecase

1. Login to application
2. Hover mouse on performance tab.
3. Hover your mouse on Configure
4. Find and click on KPIs

I tried with cypress but somehow mouse over is not working.
Kindly suggest the best way to click KPI link.

screenshots

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events) library hover command works ok

```js
cy.get('#menu__Performance')
  .realHover()

cy.contains('#menu_performance_Configure', 'Configure')
  .realHover()

cy.contains('#menu_performance_searchKpi', 'KPIs')
  .click({force:true})

cy.contains('h1', 'Search Key Performance Indicators')
```

**Note**
The last command need `force` because element clipping does occur.

**Install**

```js
npm install cypress-real-events
//or
yarn add cypress-real-events
```

**cypress/support/index.js**

```js
import "cypress-real-events/support";
```

Comment: Thanks Mihi,
It worked.
I guess this plugin is made exclusively for this kind of scenarios.

Comment: Thanks Mihi, I had exhausted my research on accomplishing this. Tried trigger('mouseover'), invoke('show'), etc but nothing worked. Your resolution worked like a charm.